# Which python version supports syntax like "except Exception, e"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, syntax

I am working with a git repo that is showing syntax error for "`except Exception, e:`"

I am using Python `2.7`.

which python version supports syntax like "`except Exception, e`"?

Comment: Switch it to 'except Exception as e:'

Comment: This syntax was removed in Python 3. And Python 2 is no more. It has ceased to be. Bereft of life, it rests in peace. It has kicked the bucked and joined the choir invisible. It's ex-Python.

Comment: Is there any way to run the code as it is, without doing any changes  in the source code

Answer (score 2):

```
except Exception, e
```

In `Python 3.x` the syntax is:

```
except Exception as e:
    ...
```

---

As you can see [`here`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) the same syntax was used in version `2.7`.

Answer (score 1):

```
except Exception,e:
```

same syntax with:

```
except Exception as e:
```

Its not related with python version, You may look PEP document.

[PEP 3110: "Catching Exceptions in Python 3000"](https://peps.python.org/pep-3110/)

Comment: Right, it's not related with Python version, I knew this but I had never read that PEP, thank you. +1

Comment: "stynax" => "syntax" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is:

```
                try:
                    do_sth()
                except Exception as ex:
                    traceback.print_exc()
                    print(ex.message)
                    print(ex.args)
```